# update values with function call to Flask

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, jinja2

I need to update realtime data with the following but `index()` and `get_data()` get called only once in the program.

How do I return values several times so that when I render template, it receives different values every time.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    value = get_data()
    print "index", value
    return render_template('index.html', session_value=value)


@app.route('/get_data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    df = sqlio.read_sql(qry, conn)
    value = df['count'][0]
    print value
    return value
```

Comment: There is no need to repeat your title in the question body. It is better to include the technology used *organically*, not as a specific prefix. The main tag (`javascript` here) is already included in the page title as used by Google.

Comment: Did you mean, you want get a random value each time you request it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put `@app.route` as a decorator, it binds it as a route within the application. Calling it later will not have the effect you intend - it calls the decorator, not the function itself. I would change your code to something like this:

```
def get_data():
    df = sqlio.read_sql(qry, conn)
    value = df['count'][0]
    print value
    return value

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    value = get_data()
    print "index", value
    return render_template('index.html', session_value=value)


@app.route('/get_data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data_route():
    value = get_data()
    # ... display your data somehow (HTML, JSON, etc.) ...
```

Comment: still getting the same values.

Comment: It looks to me like you're sending the same query every single time. If you want to get different results, you'll need to change your query.